# How can a sequence of numbers be resolved to a domain?

Tags: dns, ip, numeric

As I'm working on a project, I had the number **1373592018** copied in the clipboard. I accidentally Paste & Go'd in my web browser, which automatically added the http:// in front of the numbers.

Surprisingly, it resolved and I was prompted for username/password to the server. Upon clicking cancel it responds with this error:

> Protected Object This object on the IES-1000/SAM1008 is protected

I'm curious how this sequence of numbers is able to resolve as a domain?

It's not in any IP or DNS format that I recognize, it's very foreign to me. I was thinking it might be something on my network, so I went on a limb and pinged 1373592018 and it resolves to an Austrian IP.

Comment: I don't know how that works, but typing the URL into Chrome resolves to the IP `81.223.89.210`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a base-10 IP address. See this: http://help.network-tools.com/convert-base-10-to-ip/